# Skills in archery

Tags: technique, archery

I'm a beginning traditional archer, and I'm wondering what the point of archery is.

As far as I can tell, it's about perfect form. If you miss, you adjust your scope a little and keep trying to get perfect consistent form.

Am I missing something? Is there some other skill involved other than perfect form?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what constitutes traditional archery and how it differs from the Olympic version in your estimation? What additional skills does traditional archery require that you don't see the Olympic version testing?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are right: perfect form.

But let's think about that for a second - why are you assuming perfect form is a single skill?

It requires:

- strength
- accuracy
- discipline
- timing
- assessment of wind and conditions
- learning the scope
- etc.

In fact the the same sort of skills most sports require - which implies it fits very well into an Olympic competition.